# Pthread for php 5.6 not working

Tags: php

I have `php 5.6.31` and i have insatlled Pthread `php_pthreads-2.0.10-5.5-ts-vc11-x86`,my computer in `64 bit`,

> Still found error Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\testThread.php on line 2.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `extension=php_pthreads.dll` to your php.ini file.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php
For Linux, add: `extension=pthreads.so`

Comment: I Have added extension dll file in php/ext folder and also added extension in php.ini file ,also added pthreadVC2.dll in xampp/php folder.Please suggest me the correct version of pthread for php5.6.31

Comment: I found correct version and its working from link windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/2.0.10/  .Now I want to execute thread for php  5.2.9 , is it possible?